# Laravel 5.7 VerificationController does not extends app Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I just checked new version of Laravel and in the starting package [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) is new controller `VerificationController` in Auth subfolder.

Each controller in Auth subfolder extends `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`, but VerificationController extends `Illuminate\Routing\Controller`. Is there a reason for it, or it is just a mistake?

Comment: Boilerplate is there to get you started, you don't need to take it too literally. If you need it to extend the app controller then go right ahead.

Comment: Is there something you need from your App Controller?

Comment: sounds like an oversight if anything at all

Comment: @apokryfos I know. Question was more if there is reason, or it is oversight like @lagbox said. I would text them, but Issues in `laravel/laravel` are missing, and I don't want to report it in `laravel/framework`. But probably I will, as if there is no reason, for consistency it should follow the same rules as other controllers.

Comment: I really doubt there's any specific reason otherwise they probably would have added a comment. I mean if I were the one coding that and I had a reason to go against the convention I'd comment it.